# Won't open blend file with links to other blend files

Tags: collections

I have a master blend file which links to some other blend files. I did some cleanup work in one of the linked blend files, and tidied up some names, including changing the collection name. When I tried to open my master blend file, i got an error saying that "Collection" could not be found. So I went to the file, changed the collection name back to "Collection" and saved. Now when I try to open the master file I do not get an error, but the "Open Blend File" and "Cancel" buttons in the top right just disappear, and I am left on the list of files to open.
Is there some way to get past this and open my file?